# Removing views with tag from other ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, selector, subview

I've been trying to remove my view from an action called from other `ViewController` but I don't know how to do it
Here is my code:

```
 + (Menu *)Mostrar:(UIView *)view{
     CGRect IMGFrame = CGRectMake( 5, 20, 70, 70 );
     UIButton *boton=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:IMGFrame];
     [boton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_SuperiorBTN.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [boton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo_SuperiorBTN.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
     [boton addTarget: self action: @selector(cerrarmenu:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [boton setTag:899];
     [view addSubview: boton];
}
```

That part is called from my `MainViewController` like this

```
-(IBAction)menu:(id)sender{
    Menu *hudView = [Menu Mostrar:self.view];
}
```

Then it shows the view and when I try to close it using the button it crashes

The code to close the menu is

```
+(void)cerrarmenu:(UIView *)view{
    for (UIView *subView in view) {
        if (subView.tag == 899) {
            [subView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks
Santiago

Comment: "view.subviews" is the array of views to loop through. But please don't do this.

Comment: your view is a customview?? and you had added it to MainViewController? Now your want to remove it from MainViewController when click on the button (this button belong to your custom view). Right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the final block of code, the `UIView` instance you are using as the loop iterator and calling `subview` is not actually representative of the subviews of `view`. Here is how you should change it.

```
+(void)cerrarmenu:(UIView *)view {
    for (UIView *subView in view.subviews) {    // UIView.subviews
        if (subView.tag == 899) {
            [subView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

This takes advantage of the `@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray *subviews` provided by `UIView`.

Comment: He addTarget:self to cerrarmenu. So view = self. -> He could not remove all view from superview by this way. The only way is using delegate for this customView

Comment: @VũTuấnAnh And how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
+(void)cerrarmenu:(UIView *)view {

 [[view viewWithTag:899] removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Comment: It's best to add some commentary about the code in your answer to describe how this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I will call your viewController as "PopUpViewController".
PopViewController.h:

```
 @class PopUpViewController;
 @protocol PopUpViewControllerDelegate

     //It is delegate -> notify MainViewController to close PopUpViewController
    -(void)closeWasCalled: (PopUpViewController*)sender; 

 @end

 @interface PopUpViewController: UIViewController{
    //Some variables
 }
 //Your some properties
 //define PopUpViewControlleras delegate
 @property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyClassDelegate> delegate; 

 @end
```

PopViewController.m:

```
 -(void)btnClose{ //your close button in PopViewController
      [self.delegate closeWasCalled:self]; //MainViewController will catch that
 }
```

return to mainViewController
MainViewController.h:

```
//Add delegate
@interface PopUpViewController: UIViewController<PopViewControllerDelegate>{
    //Some variables
}
@property (strong,nonatomic) PopUpViewController* pv;

@end
```

MainViewController.m

```
//show PopUpViewController where ever you want
//example viewDidLoad

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    self.pv = [[PopViewController alloc]init];
    //set position...
    [self.view addSubView:pv];
    //dont forget set delegate
    pv.delegate = self; -> it very important
}

//using delegate
-(void)closeWasCalled: (PopUpViewController*)pvc {
    [self.pvc removeFromSuperView];
}
```

I hand write this code and not using SDK because im using windows.
But this is the way you can follow
If get stuck for this. I will answer more

This link is tutorial for create delegate: [How do I create delegates in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing method "cerrarmenu" in Menu class instead of view controller then you need to do code like

```
+(void)cerrarmenu:(UIView *)view {
    UIButton * btn= (UIButton *)sender;
    [[btn superview] removeFromSuperview];
}
```